# String и if else

Tags: java, строки, if

в общем при любом вводе выдает else, хотелось бы знать почему

```
     String num = smart.nextLine(); {
       
         if (num == "-") {
          
            System.out.print("Drossel "+ run + "first"); }
        else if (num == "+") {
           
            System.out.println("Drossel " + run + "+second"); }
        else  {
            
            System.out.println("Drossel " + run + "+end"); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сравнивания строк используйте `equals`:

```java
String num = smart.nextLine();
       
if (num.equals("-")) {
    System.out.print("Drossel "+ run + "first");
} else if (num.equals("+")) {       
    System.out.println("Drossel " + run + "+second");
} else  {
    System.out.println("Drossel " + run + "+end");
}
```